# Using cd ~ with system function in C/Objective-C doesn't cd properly

Tags: objective-c, c, system, cd

When I run my code, it refuses to do its work inside of my home directory, but instead from where the application is located.

```
system("cd ~");
system("curl https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zbfuog50rlztil/Archive.zip > tmp.zip");
system("unzip tmp.zip");
```

The file isn't put in the right location so the remainder of the program will not execute properly.

Comment: Why not just use `chdir` instead of `system`?

Comment: That seems like a great idea thank you. I was unaware of such a option. I am a little new to this.

Comment: I'm with @squiguy; the best solution is to link against `libcurl` and `libz` do all of that stuff in your own code.

Comment: please tell me this code isn't going to end up in the app store...

Comment: @Alnitak Nope, just a easy program to move some files.

Answer (score 3):

`system()` starts a shell to perform the command, then leaves the shell.

So the `cd` is performed and as the shell ends it is forgotten.

So to solve your specific issue:

Place all three commands in **one** script and execute it with **one** call to `system()`.

Comment: Ok thank you, rewriting this code to not rely on the cd should work then?

Comment: @MarkRobinson Yes. Or do it in one shell `system("cd ; curl https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zbfuog50rlztil/Archive.zip > tmp.zip");

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following

```
system("curl https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zbfuog50rlztil/Archive.zip > $HOME/tmp.zip");
system("unzip $HOME/tmp.zip -d $HOME/");
```

BTW, you should check for errors