# Why can't we change directories through system() system call in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, shell

```
system ("cd ..");
```

This doesn't produce any error but also doesn't do anything meaningful. Why?

Comment: what's your expected result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using cd ~ with system function in C/Objective-C doesn't cd properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134901/using-cd-with-system-function-in-c-objective-c-doesnt-cd-properly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `system()` function makes a `fork()` that creates a process being a copy of the initial one.

The *current directory* depends on the environment of a process (it is stored within the environment variables of a process). Thus when the *child* process, having its own environment, makes a `cd`, that affects only the *child* process, not the parent.

- Parent process: in /home/x/y
- Child process (after the fork): in /home/x/y

Doing a `cd ..` in the child process sets its local environment to /home/x
But the parent process is still in /home/x/y

Parent process waits for *child* to complete the `system` call, then continue its own execution having its own environment (*current directory*) unchanged.

Comment: That's why `cd` usually has to be a shell-builtin to actually change the working directory of the current shell and not just the one of the child.

Answer (score 6):

`system` runs the command you passed it in a different process (in a subshell). That subshell changes directories and promptly exits.

That's all perfectly valid, but perfectly useless. Use `chdir` to change your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it executes another shell. Inside this shell, the working directory changes, but that has no effect on the calling program.