# Terminal command in a ROS package is not executed

Tags: c++, ubuntu, terminal, ros, gnome-terminal

I have a little problem with a ROS node even if i think that it's mainly a C++ code problem.
What i want to do is using a script that runs in the terminal (Ubuntu 14.04) within a ROS node.
I'm doing this using the `system()` command code of the C++ language.
This script has to elaborate a .txt file stored locally on my PC; when i use the script by a normal command line method, obviously i have to navigate to the directory where my script lies first, and then i launch the script.
To replying this on my node, i use 2 `system()` instances to navigate to the directory and then to run the script.
The problem is that it seems that the node "cannot see" the command which tells it to navigate to the correct directory, so, all i can obtain is an error saying: cannot read the text file.
The only way to start the script correctly is to launch the node after i manually navigate to the directory where it lies the script.
I'm posting the code below, maybe I'm writing something bad or there is another problem that i can't see, since i'm a noob in the world of ROS and coding in general. Thank you in advance, i know that maybe it's a stupid question!

Marco

Here it is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "heart_rate_monitor");


ros::NodeHandle n;

system("cd ~/home/marco/catkin_ws/src/heart_rate_monitor");
system("get_hrv -R test.txt");


exit(0);



return 0;
}
```

Note: i tried also without the ~  .

EDIT: now it seems that's running correctly, here it is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "heart_rate_monitor");


ros::NodeHandle n;

chdir("/home/marco/catkin_ws/src/heart_rate_monitor");

system("get_hrv -R test.txt >doc.txt");


exit(0);



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the error message?

Comment: Ok, it simply says this: /usr/bin/get_hrv : Can't open test.txt

Comment: Also you should remove ~. This stands for your home directory.

Comment: Ok, i'll try it and report it! Thank you! EDIT: I'm getting this error                   sh: 1: /home/marco/catkin_ws/src/heart_rate_monitor/get_hrv: not found

Comment: get_hrv is installed in the /usr/bin directory, since it has to work for the entire system, also for files located in online databases.

Comment: ohk.. my bad .. so file test.txt is available inside /home/marco/catkin_ws/src/heart_rate_monitor folder?

Comment: Yes, test.txt is in theat folder. Do you suggest to put a copy of get_hrv in this directory too maybe?

Comment: try to give full file path once: get_hrv -R /home/marco/catkin_ws/src/heart_rate_monitor/test.txt.

Comment: Only this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `chdir` to change directory. System will create a new shell and execute the cd command. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257245/why-cant-we-change-directories-through-system-system-call-in-linux) stack overflow post for more information.

Comment: OK! I have to use: chdir cd /home/marco/catkin_ws/src/heart_rate_monitor ? Do you mean this?   EDIT: with this syntax it doesn't work. By the way with the last command  that you gave to me in the comments above it's working. But it's not totally what i want. Because, after calling the script i want it to write the results in a new text file using the command >doc.txt. The problem is that i want that file in the same directory that we are talking about. Instead it saves it in the actual directory from where i launch the node. And i want to launch the node independently of the location.

Comment: I have edited my question with the correct code, using your indications! Thank you very much! There is only a small problem. This is working only using rosrun and not roslaunch. I don't know if you know ROS and if you can help me with this, anyway thank you again @neo

Answer (score 0):

As neo pointed out, the first `system` call is changing the current directory of the `system` call, but it does not influence the parent's (i.e. your node's) current directory.

But, if I may, you should try to solve this differently. Apart from hardcoding the path being wrong, you generally should not assume to have access to the source folder on runtime (e.g. if you do an install, the source could be anywhere). Instead:

- put additional data in a new directory (e.g. 'data')
- add an install target
- retrieve the runtime path to your package using `ros::package::getPath('your_package_name')` and use the full path + "/data/test.txt" in your system call

Comment: Thank you for your advices, since I'm very new to ROS and I'm a super noob in the world of coding, any advice is like a treasure for me! Thank very much!